# Where to programmatically define ProductAttributes in Django-Oscar

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-oscar

In developing a shipping method for a Oscar Commerce project, I found that I need two attributes; one containing a float value representing the product weight (I'm using the [`Scale` class](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/shipping/scales.py) for weighing products) and an entity attribute that links to a shipping container model.

The attributes need to be assigned to any product class that has shipping required. Where/how do I create them? I have the following code, but I'm not sure where it fits.

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_model
ProductAttribute = get_model('catalogue', 'ProductAttribute')

ProductAttribute.objects.get_or_create(code='weight',
        product_class=[product class],
        defaults={
            'name': 'Weight',
            'type': ProductAttribute.FLOAT,
            })
ProductAttribute.objects.get_or_create(code='box',
        product_class=[product class],
        defaults={
            'name': 'Box used for shipping'
            'type': ProductAttribute.ENTITY,
        })
```

Where is the best place to add this code?

Comment: I add it on fixture for test purpose, and migration in production env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Django approach for this would be to use a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

If you don't want the data to be loaded automatically then an alternative would be using a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/).

We usually just set attributes up via the admin though. Also [PR #2448](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/pull/2448) is aiming to add dashboard support for adding attributes.